# FFMPEG - overlaying 4 videos not working, 2 videos is working perfectly

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trying to overlay videos using ffmpeg.

Pretty simple, using ProRes 4444 (with alpha channel).

When I overlay two videos, there is no problem.

When I try to overlay more than two, it only shows the first two entries. Is FFMPEG only capable of overlaying two videos?

```
ffmpeg.exe -y \
-i test-transparent-03.mov \
-i test-transparent-04.mov \
-i test-transparent-02.mov \
-i test-transparent-01.mov \
-filter_complex overlay -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

This command is working perfectly:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y \
-i test-transparent-03.mov \
-i test-transparent-04.mov \
-filter_complex overlay -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overlay filter works with two inputs and generates one output. You have to chain multiple overlay filters, each taking the result of the previous overlay filter as its base input

```
ffmpeg.exe -y \
-i test-transparent-03.mov \
-i test-transparent-04.mov \
-i test-transparent-02.mov \
-i test-transparent-01.mov \
-filter_complex \
 "[0][1]overlay[a];\
  [a][2]overlay[b];\
  [b][3]overlay" \
-c:v libx264 output.mp4
```